# How to trigger DM_CONVERT_CASE

Tags: gradle, findbugs

The codebase I work on has quite a few calls to no-arg version of `String#toUpperCase()` and `String#toLowerCase()`.  As is well documented elsewhere, this causes problems for people using Turkish locale. So I would like for FindBugs to tell me when this is used in our code. FindBugs supposedly has such a check (DM_CONVERT_CASE), and according to http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html this should be a default check in 3.0.1.  But I never see it reported even though for sure there are uses of those no-arg calls in our code base right now.

How can I get FindBugs to report this?

I use Gradle to run FindBugs for me:

```
findbugs {
    sourceSets = [ subProject.sourceSets.main, subProject.sourceSets.test ]
    ignoreFailures = true
    toolVersion = '3.0.1'
}
// exclude generated java sources - by explicitly setting the base source dir
findbugsMain.source = 'src/main/java'
```

Comment: How do you invoke FindBugs? In Checkstyle project we use FindBugs in version 3.0.1 and in code base we also have no-arg calls. Due to reported violations we needed some exclusions: https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/blob/a1ad6dbd260c4293be469801021f371e60fc9ae8/config/findbugs-exclude.xml#L113

Comment: Using Gradle's FindBugs support, but explicitly asking it to use 3.0.1

Comment: Still, I can't reproduce, it works for me. Please see sample project I've created: https://github.com/mkordas/DmConvertCase. Can you check whether `gradle findbugsMain` on this project generates report with `DM_CONVERT_CASE` for you?

Comment: Actually I cannot.  Unless what I am missing is how to see that in the report file.  I am expecting to be able to search for DM_CONVERT_CASE.  I do not see that in the report generated for your project either.  Here is the output I get: https://gist.github.com/sebersole/0e7b9bbeaf2ef7f9228a  This is using Gradle 2.2, maybe you are using a different version?

Comment: Actually it's not about Gradle version, just one property was missing - please see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DM_CONVERT_CASE` violations are triggered only when `reportLevel` is set to `low`. Apparently, case conversion is marked as low priority bug in FindBugs.

[Gradle documentation](https://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.quality.FindBugs.html) for `reportLevel`:

> The priority threshold for reporting bugs. If set to low, all bugs are reported. If set to medium (the default), medium and high priority bugs are reported. If set to high, only high priority bugs are reported.

You need to add to extend your config with:

```
findbugs {
    sourceSets = [ subProject.sourceSets.main, subProject.sourceSets.test ]
    ignoreFailures = true
    toolVersion = '3.0.1'
    reportLevel = 'low'
}
// exclude generated java sources - by explicitly setting the base source dir
findbugsMain.source = 'src/main/java'
```

You can see it working in the project I've created while trying to reproduce the problem: https://github.com/mkordas/DmConvertCase.

**EDIT:**

For people using Maven, you need to configure `findbugs-maven-plugin` in the following way:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <threshold>Low</threshold>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks for that Michal!  Out of curiosity, can I do the other?  Can I instance somehow make FindBugs treat `DM_CONVERT_CASE` as a higher level?  Even at medium it reports so many things I consider dubious, which make it even more bizarre that it reports a real problem like this as low.

Comment: Looked into this some more.  `reportLevel`/`threshold` should speak to the `confidence` (`priority`) of the bug, which is supposed to indicate how "likely" the reported code is an actual bug, which in turn is supposed to be based on the difficult in making that determination.  A bug that needs to read across many bytecode instructions is said to have a lower confidence than a bug that needs to read just one or 2 instructions.  Could be wrong, but it seems to me that the `DM_CONVERT_CASE` determination needs to just look at one instruction, so why is this considered to be such low confidence?

Comment: Maybe authors meant that this may be a bug, but not necessarily - depends on the context of usage. 
I think that priority can be changed using Filter File - more info at http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/filter.html

Comment: I only see how to define a confidence/priority as part of the match criteria, not how to alter it.  Although to be honest, the documentation for these files is not great and maybe I just miss something.

Comment: @SteveEbersole A rule's `confidence` also measures how likely the rule is flagging a real bug. Code that *may* be suspect in rare cases will get a low `confidence` even when it is matched in a single line of code. It sounds like this bug may need to be changed if this is a more common problem than the author's realize.

Comment: @DavidHarkness Yes, I understand that.  I have requested an increase in the confidence of this as a bug with FindBugs : https://sourceforge.net/p/findbugs/feature-requests/343/  For the time being, this is always considered a bug as far as I am concerned for Hibernate and would like to make sure this is reported with a higher confidence.  Is that possible in FindBugs via config?